# Can I change ViewPager's swipe direction from LTR to RTL?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I want to know if I can change swiping direction of ViewPager from **LTR** to **RTL**. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            viewPager.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }
```